# Nodejs Smartsheet API Error when trying to move row to another sheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have been working on a simple production management process based around smartsheet. The code that I have been running has been working fine on my Ubuntu machine, then I copied it over to my Parrot Linux machine running the same node version and it won't find a row that exists. Below is the request:

```
      var copyRow = {
        "rowIds": artToProdRowsToCopy,
        "to": {
          "sheetId": productionId
        }
      };

      // Set options
      var options = {
        sheetId: artId,
        body: copyRow,
        queryParameters: {
          include: "all"
        }
      };
      console.log(options);
      // Copy the normal engraved rows from art to production
      smartsheet.sheets.copyRowToAnotherSheet(options)
        .then(function(results) {
          callback1(null, results);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

The log output of options:

```
{ sheetId: 8129017524546436,
  body: 
   { rowIds: [ 8886954296800644 ],
      to: { sheetId: 6941481487333252 } },
   queryParameters: { include: 'all' } }
```

The error:

```
{ statusCode: 404,
  errorCode: 1006,
  message: 'Not Found',
  refId: 'zjl2z56296l9' }
```

I'm running node v8.9.1, on Parrot Linux 3.9.

I've checked that each of these sheet and row ID #'s are correct and they all are (the ones in the examples are not real however). Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Adding debug info:

```
[Smartsheet] 2017-11-20T20:22:55.876Z[   INFO] POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/8129017124546436/rows//copy?include=all
[Smartsheet] 2017-11-20T20:22:55.876Z[VERBOSE] Request Payload (preview): {"rowIds":[2759271070885764,3212501789763460,4576920289470340,8982631438149508,2962733838690180,8886959296800644],"to":{"sheetId":6941441487333252}}
[Smartsheet] 2017-11-20T20:22:55.876Z[  DEBUG] Request Payload (full): {"rowIds":[2759271070885764,3212501789763460,4576920289470340,8982631438149508,2962733838690180,8886959296800644],"to":{"sheetId":6941441487333252}}
[Smartsheet] 2017-11-20T20:22:56.155Z[  ERROR] Request failed after 0 retries
[Smartsheet] 2017-11-20T20:22:56.156Z[  ERROR] POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/8129017124546436/rows//copy?include=all
[Smartsheet] 2017-11-20T20:22:56.156Z[  ERROR] Response: Failure (HTTP 404)
Error Code: 1006 - Not Found
Ref ID: 85bn0m2j8oki
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any obvious issues with your request structure. Typically, the **404 Not Found** error is related to an issue with the request URI, rather than the contents of the request itself. i.e., a **404 Not Found** error means that, for some reason or another, the request URI is not reachable.

The URI for the **Copy Row(s)** request is:

`POST /sheets/{sheetId}/rows/copy`

A few troubleshooting suggestions:

- Verify that the casing of all characters in the request URI are lowercase.
- Verify that the sheet corresponding to the `sheetId` value in the request URI exists.
- Verify that the user who owns the API Access token that you're specifying in the `Authorization` header of the **Copy Row(s)** API request does indeed have access to the sheet corresponding to the `sheetId` value in the request URI.

As described in the [Troubleshooting](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#troubleshooting) section of the API docs, I'd suggest that you use a tool like Fiddler or Charles HTTP Proxy to examine the raw HTTP request that your app is sending, then you can investigate/verify the items I've listed above.

**Update #1**

Thanks for updating your post with debugging info. Based on that, it looks like your request URI contains an extra slash between the words `rows` and `copy`:

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/8129017124546436/rows//copy?include=all
```

Perhaps this is causing your problem?

**Update #2**

I've been able to reproduce the **Not Found** error in Postman if my Request URI contains two slashes between the words `rows` and `copy`(like your debug output shows). Removing one of these slashes fixes the issue.  That is, your request should look like this (only one slash between the words `rows` and `copy`).

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/8129017124546436/rows/copy?include=all
```

Comment: I just added what the debugging looks like.

Comment: Working on getting Node to except the self signed Charles cert . I'll let you know if I find anything more.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more info, based on the debug output you've added to your post.

Comment: Added "Update #2" to my answer to provide more info.  If this resolves your issue, please mark this answer as "Accepted" so that others may benefit from this info in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Just marked it. Sorry about the delay and thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like our SDK bug. Stay tuned for a fix.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in version 1.0.3 - now on Github and npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartsheet
https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk/releases/tag/v1.0.3

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!